# Why do we need atomic boolean when overriding call adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am watching one of the google android samples, and I am having a hard time what exactly the variable **started** is supposed to do. Here is the [class](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/LiveDataCallAdapter.kt#L43).

Answer (score 0):

An **AtomicBoolean** is used in applications such as atomically updated flags.

```
compareAndSet(expect: Boolean, update: Boolean)
```

Atomically sets the value to the given updated value if the current value == the expected value.

This is used to prevent concurrent modification exception.

Comment: Yes but why do we need it here in this example